# How to intentionally install vulnerable package

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I want to intentionally install the old vulnerable version of the liblog4j2-java package in order to test the CVE-2021-44228 vulnerability. I'm using an Ubuntu machine.

I know I can list old package versions with `apt-cache madison liblog4j2-java`, but are these still vulnerable?

How can I download the old, but official packages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fixed packages are shipped in the updates and/or security repositories; the old, vulnerable packages are still available in the base repository. You can therefore install the latter by specifying the desired version:

- in 18.04, `sudo apt install liblog4j2-java=2.10.0-2`;
- in 20.04, `sudo apt install liblog4j2-java=2.11.2-1`;
- in 21.04 and 21.10, `sudo apt install liblog4j2-java=2.13.3-1`.

The versions are shown by `apt-cache madison`.

Further reading: [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92019/412264) and [USN-5192-1: Apache Log4j 2 vulnerability](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5192-1).